# Image alt text not displaying on WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have added an alt text on my image, but it doesn't display on homepage. Is there a way to get the `alt` text to display with the image without re-attaching the image, since the image was previously added on the site without `alt` text.

http://prntscr.com/lenin2
http://prntscr.com/lenj0o

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The "alt" text isn't the text which is displayed - that would be the `figcaption` text.

If you add a caption text directly when you insert the image (or when you edit it ) in Wordpress, WP automatically creates a shortcode that puts the image and the text into a `figure` element which contains both the image and the caption text (inside a `figcaption` tag).

(And if you don't add a caption text in WP's image edit box, the image is inserted without the `figure` tag, as a regular `img` tag. Whatever the `alt` attribute in there contains, will *not* be displayed - it only serves for accessibility purposes or is displayed if the image is missing)

Comment: So there is a need to edit the post and reinsert the image so that the changes will take affect?

Comment: Yes and no: You don't need to reinsert the image, just to edit it and add the caption text. Then WP will crete the `figure` element around it.